# can't resolve react/jsx-dev-runtime' after changing "type":"module" in package.json

Tags: javascript, reactjs, package.json

```
{
  "name": "furniture",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  **"type": "module"**,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.7.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.6.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.2.5",
    "@mui/material": "^5.2.6",
    "@mui/styles": "^5.2.3",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "dot-env": "^0.0.1",
    "mongoose": "^6.1.6",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "react-swipeable-views": "^0.14.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Compiled with problems:X

**ERROR in ./src/index.js 9:0-58**

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react/jsx-dev-runtime' in '/home/reddragon/Documents/Projects/furniture/src'
Did you mean 'jsx-dev-runtime.js'?
BREAKING CHANGE: The request 'react/jsx-dev-runtime' failed to resolve only because it was resolved as fully specified
(probably because the origin is strict EcmaScript Module, e. g. a module with javascript mimetype, a '*.mjs' file, or a '*.js' file where the package.json contains '"type": "module"').
The extension in the request is mandatory for it to be fully specified.
Add the extension to the request.

**When I do babel configuration it will create a mess.**

Comment: I've got the same problem...changed package.json with "type": "module" in order to fix another issue and got a whole nother world of problems.